# Absolute path in Magento2

Tags: path, media, absolute, magento2

How can I get the absolute path of a media file in Magento2?
I write a function to get the absolute path, but it is not working.

```
public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem */
        $filesystem = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface $mediaDirectory */
        $mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $mediaPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath();
        return $mediaPath;
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

app/autoloader.php

contains:

```
/**
 * Shortcut constant for the root directory
 */
define('BP', dirname(__DIR__));
```

One could do something like:

```
$mediaPath = BP.'/pub/media/';
```

That said, Magento\Framework\Filesystem via dependency injection is my preferred method

Answer (score 3):

You can use to get media and base Absolute path in magento 2 like:

```
$storeManager = $_objectMedia->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();

$mediaUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

$_baseurl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
```

Try it's working fine for me....

Answer (score 2):

```
/* @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $om /

$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$dir = $om->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem'); 

$mediadir = $dir->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA); 

$path = $mediadir->create('foldername');
```

try it its working for me..

Answer (score 2):

**With Object manager:**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$directoryList = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList'); 
$media = $directoryList->getPath('media');
```

With dependency injection:

**Use class `\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList**

```
protected $_directoryList;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList
    ...
) {
    $this->_directoryList = $directoryList;  
}
```

**For Root Folder**

```
$this->_directoryList->getRoot();
```

**For media Folder**

```
$this->_directoryList->getPath('media');
```

**Other Folders**

```
// Get app folder
$this->_directoryList->getPath('app');

// Get etc Folder
$this->_directoryList->getPath('etc');

// Get public folder
$this->_directoryList->getPath('pub');

// Get var folder
$this->_directoryList->getPath('var');
```

Answer (score 2):

Relying on the BP isn't a good way to go this, BP should only be used in the low layers in Magento. 
Magneto has init config values where the media directory could possibly be outside of the base path. You should rely on the \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList object instead.

In the bootstrap you can see:
\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::createFilesystemDirectoryList

```
class Bootstrap
{

    /**
     * Creates instance of filesystem directory list
     *
     * @param string $rootDir
     * @param array $initParams
     * @return DirectoryList
     */
    public static function createFilesystemDirectoryList($rootDir, array $initParams)
    {
        $customDirs = [];
        if (isset($initParams[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS])) {
            $customDirs = $initParams[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS];
        }
        return new DirectoryList($rootDir, $customDirs);
    }

}
```

This means if you set $_SERVER variables during bootstrap:

```
$tmpDir = '/var/tmpfs_mount';
$applicationDir = '/var/www/html/magento';
$loggingDir = '/var/log/restricted';

$params = $_SERVER;
$filesystemsDirs = $params[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS];

$filesystemsDirs[DirectoryList::CONFIG]    = [DirectoryList::PATH => $applicationDir . "/var/cache"];
$filesystemsDirs[DirectoryList::MEDIA]     = [DirectoryList::PATH => $tmpDir . "/var/cache"];
$filesystemsDirs[DirectoryList::GENERATED] = [DirectoryList::PATH => $tmpDir . "/generated"];
$filesystemsDirs[DirectoryList::CACHE]     = [DirectoryList::PATH => $tmpDir . "/var/cache"];
$filesystemsDirs[DirectoryList::LOG]       = [DirectoryList::PATH => $loggingDir . "/var/log"];

$params[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] = $filesystemsDirs;

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
```

To do via the object manager, add the DirectoryList object to the constructor:

```
use \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class MyModuleClass
{
  /**
   * @var DirectoryList
   */
  private $directoryList;

  /**
   * @param DirectoryList $directoryList
   */
  public function __construct(DirectoryList $directoryList)
  {
      $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
  }

  /**
   * @var DirectoryList
   */
  private $mediaPath;

  public function getMediaAbsolutePath(){
       if (!$this->mediaPath){
           $this->mediaPath = $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
       }
       return $this->mediaPath;
  } 

}
```

Please note this will only get you the path, but it won't validate if via the PathValidator introduced in Magento 2.3. This PathValidator ensures that the path is allowed within the installation, you'll need to validate it yourself

vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/PathValidator.php

P.S I haven't tested the code, I've just eye'd it from memory, so if it breaks let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$fileSystem = $om->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem');  
$mediaDirectory = $fileSystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use blow code for geting absolute url of an image you have uploaded in product page.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$b_url = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
                    ->getStore()
                    ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

// here product_badge is custom image attribute code, replace it with yours attribute.

$_product = $block->getProduct();
$product_badge = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_badge')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
?>
<img  src="<?php echo $b_url.'/catalog/product'.$product_badge; ?>" />
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$rootDirectory = Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                    ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer? [From review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11855039)